# Having issue with hover in css

Tags: html, css

I have this in html

```
<nav>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="tabs">
            <a href="#one">headliners</a>
            <a href="#two">passes</a>
            <a href="#three">experience</a>
            <a href="#four">travel</a>
            <a href="#five">full lineup</a>
        </div><!--End tabs-->
    </div>
</nav>
```

and am trying to make it so that whenever i hover over any of the `a` tags, the words change to `color:#d10f82;`

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us what did you try to do pls

Answer (score 0):

Like `a:hover { color: #d10f82; }` ?

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/54umjsm7/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your anchor tags, then use the hover psuedo

```
.hovered-anchor:hover {
color:#d10f82
}
```

Comment: I used class in case you don't want all of your a tags getting the same color

Answer (score 0):

With this structure

```
<nav>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="tabs">
            <a href="#one">headliners</a>
            <a href="#two">passes</a>
            <a href="#three">experience</a>
            <a href="#four">travel</a>
            <a href="#five">full lineup</a>
        </div><!--End tabs-->
    </div>
</nav>
```

This is as specific as you can get

```
  nav > .inner > .tabs > a:hover {
    color:#d10f82;
    }
```

```css
a {

  color: black;

}

nav > .inner > .tabs > a:hover {

  color: #d10f82;

}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="tabs">
      <a href="#one">headliners</a>
      <a href="#two">passes</a>
      <a href="#three">experience</a>
      <a href="#four">travel</a>
      <a href="#five">full lineup</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```